# How do I make a DNS entry for a not yet started container available in another container?

Tags: docker, docker-network

I am trying to run a cluster of containers. Each instance is given the list of the hosts and ports of the other instances via an environment variable.
I want to use docker networking (i.e., NOT host networking). My idea was to give each instance an explicit hostname with the "--name" (or --network-alias) run option.

So I would like to start them like this:

```
docker run --name x1 -e clusterMembers=x2:12345,x3:12345 --network=mynet -d my/image
docker run --name x2 -e clusterMembers=x1:12345,x3:12345 --network=mynet -d my/image
docker run --name x3 -e clusterMembers=x1:12345,x2:12345 --network=mynet -d my/image
```

The problem is that when I start the first container which references the hostnames x2 and x3, these hostnames do not yet exist via the Docker networking DNS. My server starts up, does a lookup, which fails, and the server exits again (no, I cannot change the code to retry the DNS lookup).
Note that the server will not fail if the other instances are not yet reachable... it is only that it does not tolerate a failed DNS lookup.

Any idea how to make the hostnames x2 and x3 available to container x1 (and the hostname x3 to container x2)?

I tried the "--add-host" option to add a fake entry to the /etc/hosts file, but of course this fake entry will then "shadow" the DNS lookup, and the server will never see the right IP address even once the other instances are started.

Any approach to get this done, other than using host networking?

---

The solution I came up with based on the suggestion by BMitch was to take the wait-for-it script, adapt it slightly so that instead of "pinging" a host + port it would instead just do a DNS lookup for a given host.

Then, in my container entrypoint script, I first extract the hostnames from the "clusterMembers" environment variable in my example above and the use my wait-for-dns script with each hostname.

Comment: Do you have any reason for not using a tool like Docker Compose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change or add an entrypoint in the image that does something like a [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it). Then you can start your containers in any order and not need to worry about race conditions or injecting the DNS address for a container that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: wait-for-it looks like an interesting approach - alas, it won't work out of the box, since it pings a host+port, so the other containers need to open a port, but for that they need to start the service, and for that the other services need to be up and running. Maybe I can adapt wait-for-it so that it just waits for a successful DNS lookup.

Comment: With a shell script, you can do a `while ! ping -n 1 $host; do sleep 5; done` (might be `-c 1`). Doesn't need to be wait-for-it.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried the "--add-host" option to add a fake entry to the /etc/hosts file, but of course this fake entry will then "shadow" the DNS lookup, and the server will never see the right IP address even once the other instances are started.

I would suggest you to combine this approach with assigning particular IP address to every container:

`docker run --name x1 --add-host="x2:172.17.42.102" --add-host="x3:172.17.42.103" --ip="172.17.42.101" --network=mynet -d my/image`

Comment: I would rather not have to assign IPs explicitly, but this sounds like a possible fallback, if wait-for-DNS or whatever the adapted wait-for-it script mentioned by BMitch doesn't work for me.

Comment: @PalatinateJ consider this just as a workaround. However, I must say that the software running inside your containers looks very poor. Modern systems, especially distributed systems, must be fault-tolerant for such kind of a trivial errors.

Comment: you are of course right, the software should treat a DNS lookup problem just like it treats any other connection problem to the named instance (which it handles perfectly well, BTW...), but it is a third party product, and so I cannot really change it.